# Converting HttpRequestMessage to OwinRequest and OwinResponse to HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

I have a web API message handler `MyHandler` that I want to run in OWIN pipeline as a middleware. So configuring the handler like this.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseHttpMessageHandler(new MyHandler());

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultWebApi",
                "{controller}/{id}",
                    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Handler is very simple and does nothing.

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
             HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    { // <--- breakpoint here

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }
}
```

I put a break point inside `SendAsync` and it does break but the following `base.SendAsync` bombs silently and I see `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Net.Http.dll`.

I can quite easily add `MyHandler` to `config.MessageHandlers` and it will run perfect in the Web API pipeline but that's not what I want to do. I want to run `MyHandler` in the OWIN pipeline. Is this possible at all? It should be. Otherwise, there is no point in having the extension method `UseHttpMessageHandler`, I guess. Just that I couldn't figure out a way to do what I want to do.

Comment: I think you're confusing the concepts of message handlers and delegating handlers. A message handler is just something that takes a request and returns a response.

Comment: I do understand the difference between message handler and a delegating handler. A delegating handler is a message handler and I was just hoping that I will be able to use a delegating handler in place of message handler and magically it will run in the OWIN pipeline like it runs in a Web API pipeline and apparently it is not possible, based on Kiran's reply. I agree I'm too ambitious. Thanks for looking at my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this experience needs to be improved as the exception is silently ignored.

For your above scenario, you would need to derive from `HttpMessageHandler` instead of `DelegatingHandler` as the delegating handler would try to delegate the request to handlers after it.(example: The exception mentions `Message=The inner handler has not been assigned`)

For example, the following would work:

```
appBuilder.UseHttpMessageHandler(new MyNonDelegatingHandler());

public class MyNonDelegatingHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new StringContent("Hello!");

        return Task.FromResult<HttpResponseMessage>(response);
    }
}
```

And for creating a chain of handlers, you could do the following:

```
appBuilder.UseHttpMessageHandler(HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(innerHandler: new MyNonDelegatingMessageHandler(),
           handlers: new DelegatingHandler[] { new DelegatingHandlerA(), new DelegatingHandlerB() }));
```

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies quite a bit. One final question. Can only `HttpMessageHandler` be turned into an OWIN middleware using the adapter? I was hoping we could something like that for delegating handlers too. In my case, I need to look at the response message too.

Comment: I see. For some clarity, the two `UseWebApi` extensions hookup a `HttpServer` and the `UseHttpMessageHandler` extension doesn't hookup it and gives you the options of building a pipeline like i mentioned in the post. Now coming to your question about looking at the response, I think you would need to hook in a general OWIN middleware where you can inspect the response and not a HttpMessageHandler. The request pipeline would then look like : `->MyOwinInspectorMiddleware->HttpMessageHandlerAdapter->HttpServer(HandlerA -> HanlerB -> etc)`

Comment: @KiranChalla Hi, where is this `UseHttpMessageHandler` extension? I cannot find it in Katana source.

Comment: @Aliostad: its part of System.Web.Http.Owin