# Logging response and request to OAuth provider

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

Is there a way to capture the response from requests served by OAuth? Specifically, I need to log the request and response from `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials()`.

I've tried extending `OwinMiddleware` and overriding `Invoke` as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679644/owin-onsendingheaders-callback-reading-response-body?lq=1), but I'm unable to read the response body. I'd like to use a message handler as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656066/converting-httprequestmessage-to-owinrequest-and-owinresponse-to-httpresponsemes) demonstrates, but I don't have `UseHttpMessageHandler` on my `AppBuilder` object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

**Update**

Modifying the example provided in Brock's excellent [video](http://brockallen.com/2014/02/28/lidnug-intro-to-owin-and-katana), here's what I need to do:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(typeof(MW1));

        app.Map("/api", fooApp => {
            fooApp.Use<MW2>();
        });
    }
}

public class MW1 {
    Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task> next;
    public MW1(Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> env) {
        var ctx = new OwinContext(env);
        await next(env);
        // I need to be able to read: <h1>MW2 called</h1> written by MW2
        var body = ctx.Response.Body;
        // body.CanRead = False
    }
}

public class MW2 {
    Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task> next;
    public MW2(Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> env) {
        var ctx = new OwinContext(env);
        await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("<h1>MW2 called</h1>");
        await next(env);
    }
}
```

I actually need to read the response sent from the OAuth provider, but I assume it would be the same process.

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement an OWIN middleware component that sits in front of the OAuth AS middleware?

Comment: Sorry, all this is new to me. Could you go into more detail?

Comment: Here's a video from a UG talk I did on OWIN/Katana: http://brockallen.com/2014/02/28/lidnug-intro-to-owin-and-katana/

Comment: Great presentation, Brock. I learned a lot of good stuff. Can you take a look at my update? Is it possible to read the response body from the Invoke method?

Comment: You'd need to replace the OWIN Stream with your own.